# Select desired Outlook Calendar Items using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

How can we select desired calendar items? ideally, the calendar items under mouse selection. There's a difference between selecting cells and calendar items within Outlook Calendar. I want to select all calendar items within selected cells.

Comment: Make sure that, View is the Calendar view not ListView.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your Outlook Calendar arrange be set to **Month** ? I'm afraid that there is no good way to do it By VBA code.